# Resizing UITextField while editing

Tags: ios, cocoa, uitextfield

When i click the text field and add new characters, existing characters are moved to the left and disappear. I would like to change the width of the text field instead.

I tried to change the frame of the text field but it did not work.
Is there a solution

Comment: It would be better if you can post some code or provide more information,like you are using autolayout or setting width with frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` add this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textFieldWidthConstraint.constant = yourNewWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`, then determine text width like this:

```
CGFloat width =  [aTextField.text sizeWithFont:aTextField.font].width;
```

and then change frame or constraints (*depending on whether you're using auto-layout or not*) of your `UITextField` accordingly.